# Getting tuple from command line arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples

Have a question,

I'm writing a python-script and need to pass argument to the script from cmd.

My code to implement this little feature:

```
import sys

cars = sys.argv[1]
```

From command line, I type the next command:

`python my_script.py ("Opel", "Nissan", 'Reno')`

But when I checked the results, it was not a tuple, it was a string. How can I get a tuple from argument?

Comment: @Sherzod I have already read this topic, but it doesn't help me, I need a solution for this case

Answer (score 4):

The command line does not know about Python data structures. All you get from there are strings. You can create them in Python, however:

```
cars = sys.argv[1].split()
# cars = tuple(sys.argv[1].split())
```

and call script as

```
python my_script.py "Opel Nissan Reno"
```

For more advanced argument processing, you should consider using the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) module.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work, I checked cars variable with isinstance method to understand what is the type.

Comment: Did you see my uncommented variant which makes it a `tuple` instead of a `list`.

Answer (score 0):

command line is not define tuple.
try this from command line

```cmd
python my_script.py "Opel" "Nissan" "Reno"
```

```python
import sys
# get from 1 to end
cars = sys.argv[1:]
```

Comment: You can see cars with `print(tuple(cars))`

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--data', nargs='+', type=str)
args = parser.parse_args()
my_tuple = tuple(args.data)
print(type(my_tuple)) # Check type
```

Run:

```
python my_script.py --data Opel Nissan Reno
```

Output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```